# Mirror MacBook Desktop on iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, remote-desktop

I was wondering if anyone have any ideas of how you could mirror a MacBook desktop on to an iPhone. I'm not looking for an app to install but a way to program it myself. What would be the best approach?

And to clarify, I'm not looking for a way to mirror my iPhone to my computer, but the other way around.

Thanks for any answers you might have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are talking about can be achieved in a number of ways. You need a server component running on the MacBook, which vends a video stream of the MacBook display(s) over a suitably secure network connection, and your app on the iPhone behaving as a client to this video stream. VNC (Vertual Network Computing) is the established, open, system for doing this. Conveniently macOS has a built in VNC server (Screen Sharing in the Sharing preference pane), so the server side is already done. Your app will need to implement the VNC client. I suggest you start by looking for existing open source implementations for this functionality, http://cocoapods.org